# How to trigger a job in Jenkins to start at a specific time

Tags: jenkins

I need to schedule a job in Jenkins to run in every 5 minutes. I could do that: */5 * * * *
However, the peculiarity here, is that this job should start at 3:05pm and then run indefinitely.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What do you mean "run indefinitely"? Does it mean that it should stop at midnight?

Comment: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Comment: What is your expectation? The scheduler only starts your Jenkins job and it doesn't stop it. The run-time depends on the content of your Jenkins job. It would be nice if you share your expectation then perhaps somebody can answer your question!